# Blazor webassembly manipulate item(s) in svg image at runtime

Tags: c#, html, svg, blazor

An svg image (with some elements) is displayed on a webassembly page and needs to be manipulated at runtime. The affected items in this example svg are:

1. Text item (below green)
2. Circle item (below blue)

Blazor project example with added svg image displayed in page "Counter.razor": [Github](https://github.com/vcarlucci/SvgImageExample)

The manipulation must be done **without CSS**, so in the razor HTML or in razor C# part. How this can be achieved?

Note: It is important that the svg is in a file like described here, because in reality it will be a much more complex image with some few animated items.

```html
@* SVG : manipulate elements inside it*@
<img src="/svg_data/test.svg" alt="image" width="340" id="Illustration"/>
```

Here the svg image:
[image]

Here the page code:

```cs
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>


@* SVG : manipulate elements inside this svg*@
<img src="/svg_data/test.svg" alt="image" width="340" id="Illustration"/>


@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        // -> update Illustration svg item "text" with currentCount value
        // if(currentCount >= 5) -> change background color of svg item "circle"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to paste the svg code in the razor page like this changing the variables you want:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="171px" height="71px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 171 71" content="&lt;mxfile host=&quot;Electron&quot; modified=&quot;2022-06-09T12:39:19.202Z&quot; agent=&quot;5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) draw.io/19.0.3 Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Electron/19.0.3 Safari/537.36&quot; etag=&quot;DJvfIeUmnxomRYf_Gf6z&quot; version=&quot;19.0.3&quot; type=&quot;device&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram id=&quot;zbXMXlBePv6qebmGt9Y5&quot; name=&quot;Seite-1&quot;&gt;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&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;"><defs>
  <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%" id="mx-gradient-666666-1-191919-1-s-0">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(25, 25, 25); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="70" fill="url(#mx-gradient-666666-1-191919-1-s-0)" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/>
  <rect x="10" y="0" width="150" height="30" fill="none" stroke="none" pointer-events="all"/>
<g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)">
  <switch>
    <foreignObject pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 148px; height: 1px; padding-top: 15px; margin-left: 11px;">
        <div data-drawio-colors="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); " style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0px; text-align: center;">
          <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; overflow-wrap: normal;">ShowActualValue</div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </foreignObject>
    <text x="85" y="19" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">@ShowActualValue</text>
  </switch>
</g>
    <ellipse cx="145" cy="45" rx="15" ry="15" fill="@bgColor" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" pointer-events="all"/>
</g>
  <switch>
      <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"/>
      <a transform="translate(0,-5)" xlink:href="https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/svg-export-text-problems" target="_blank">
        <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Text is not SVG - cannot display</text>
    </a>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

and in code section

```
@code 
{
  string ShowActualValue = "@ShowActualValue";
  string bgColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

  private void ChangeText(string text)
  {
     ShowActualValue = text;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Santiago, thank you very much for your great contribution here! I appreciate your solution, for some topics this seems nice and usable. But, in the question I referred to a svg file, which is really a important requirement. The reason, in reality we will have a bigger svg image representing a building or so, where we want to have some few animated items inside the view :)

Comment: I am thinking to something iterating thourgh all svg file elements and search by a certain id/name and when found, make the appropriate change to the element..